# UIAutomation getting progress value every second instead of just once

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety, ui-automation, invoke

Hey all I am am currently getting the value for the progress bar that a application is using when I use the following code:

```
Dim progressBarThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Me.ThreadProcSafe))

Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf progressBarThread.Start))

Do
     status = range.Current.Value.ToString
     numwaits += 1
     'Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf progressBarThread.Start))
     Wait(5)
Loop While status <> 100 AndAlso numwaits < 50

LogMessage("100%" + Environment.NewLine)

Delegate Sub SetTextCallback([text] As String)

Private Sub ThreadProcSafe()
    Me.SetText(status)
End Sub

Private Sub SetText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
    Else
        Me.ProgressBar1.Value = [text]
    End If
End Sub
```

Problem being is that it only gets the value **once** and doesn't constantly update the value as I am wanting. As you see in the code above, I tried to use **Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf progressBarThread.Start))** within the loop in order to see if it would update the value that way but it does not work and causes an error.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `ProgressBar1.Value = [text]` value is numeric, you are assigning text; status is similarly mangled

Comment: @Plutonix The progress bar works as-is but only once. I am trying to **continuously update the progress** until it reaches 100.